# How to stop a Lottie animation manually

Tags: swift, xcode, lottie

I use the Lottie animation library in XCode. But when I go to another page, the animation is running in the background. When I go back the main page, the animation is running twice and there is too much RAM being consumed. How can I fix this problem? and how can I stop the animation after a specific time?

```
import UIKit
import Lottie

class CoffeeSpecialFortunePageVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBAction func PopUpIn(_ sender: Any) {
        animateIn(desiredView: PopupBlur)
        animateIn(desiredView: popupView)
        animation()
    }
    @IBAction func SuccesBtn(_ sender: UIView) {
        animateOut(desiredView: PopupBlur)
        animateOut(desiredView: popupView)         
    }
         
    @IBOutlet var popupView: AnimationView!
    @IBOutlet var PopupBlur: UIVisualEffectView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        PopupBlur.bounds = self.view.bounds
        popupView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width * 0.9, height: self.view.bounds.height * 0.4)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func animation() {
        popupView! = .init(name: "check1")
        popupView?.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(popupView!)
        popupView?.play()
        popupView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        popupView.frame.size.height = 350
        popupView.frame.size.width = 350
        popupView.center.x = view.center.x
        popupView.center.y = view.center.y 

             
    }

    func animateIn(desiredView: UIView) {
        let backgraundview = self.view!
        backgraundview.addSubview(desiredView)
        desiredView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
        desiredView.alpha = 0
        desiredView.center = backgraundview.center
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations:{
            desiredView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            desiredView.alpha = 1
            
        })                       
    }
    func animateOut(desiredView: UIView) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            desiredView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
            desiredView.alpha = 0
        },completion: {_ in
            desiredView.removeFromSuperview()                
            
        })            
    }    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you `init`  `popView` only once?

Comment: Great! This is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the `play(fromProgress...)` API's that `Lottie provides`

```
animationView.play(
    fromProgress: animationView.currentProgress,
    toProgress: 1,
    loopMode: .playOnce,
    completion: { [weak self] completed in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
            self.stopLoopAndTranstion(to: animation, endIn: image)
        }
    }
)
```

This will ensure that your current animation will finish and in completion block you can do your finishing work

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solutions:

1. Create a notifier when the app goes to the background for pause and when back to the foreground

   ```
    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

    animationView = .init(name: "lang")
    animationView!.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)
    animationView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    animationView!.loopMode = .loop
    animationView!.animationSpeed = 0.5
    view.addSubview(animationView!)
    animationView!.play()
   ```

   }
2. This will invoke notification methods when the app moves to background and foreground

   ```
    @objc func appMovedToBackground() 
    {

       print("App moved to background!")

       animationView!.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    @objc func appBecomeActive() 
    {

    print("App become active")
    //animationView!.play()

    animationView = .init(name: "lang")
    animationView!.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)
    animationView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    animationView!.loopMode = .loop
    animationView!.animationSpeed = 0.5
    view.addSubview(animationView!)
    animationView!.play()
    }
   ```

This will solve your problem....... For sure